# Why int32(0) is not reflect.DeepEqual to type Zero in Golang?

Tags: reflection, go, swagger

I found this sort of validation in **go-swagger** package.

```
// Required validates an interface for requiredness
func Required(path, in string, data interface{}) *errors.Validation {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    if reflect.DeepEqual(reflect.Zero(val.Type()), val) {
        return errors.Required(path, in)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I tried to use it and it forced me for some thoughts.

Why the following is not a true statement?

```
exper := int32(0)
reflect.DeepEqual(
   reflect.Zero(reflect.ValueOf(exper).Type()), 
   reflect.ValueOf(exper)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the [godocs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) of `reflect.Value`:

> Using == on two Values does not compare the underlying values they
>   represent, but rather the contents of the Value structs. To compare
>   two Values, compare the results of the Interface method.

[Play](https://play.golang.org/p/ZyfUnY8YrH)

```
package main

import "reflect"

func main() {
  //var i int32
  exper := int32(0)
  r := reflect.DeepEqual(
    reflect.Zero(reflect.ValueOf(exper).Type()).Interface(),
    reflect.ValueOf(exper).Interface(),
  )
  println(r)  // true 
}
```